# universal content manager

Tags: content-management

I found one limitation in Oracle UCM. Well it might not be limitation but I am not able to figure it out yet:

I didn't find mapping between metadata and content type. What if I wish to associate different set of metadata with different content type which is likely the case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Content profiles for this. You should find these described in the documentation. These are created via the Configuration Manager applet. You need to create a trigger field (for doctype, for example) and then your profiles. You then create rules which you associate with each profile that will specify which metadata applies for the profile in question.